# Enable Always Ask Before Opening this Type of File in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, privileges

I recently downloaded and wanted to install whatsup app on my pc.

But when the exe file started with prompt to run it or not i mistakenly unchecked "Always Ask Before Opening this Type of File" :/.

And the question is, Enable Always Ask Before Opening this Type of File in Windows 10?

Can't find the answer. Found for XP, Windows 7... But nothing for Windows 10 :/.

It has to be solution for Windows 10.

Comment: See if this helps....https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/stop-windows-10-from-asking-for-admin-rights-to-run-unknown-apps/

Comment: @Moab I think it doesn't. It's not this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on [Chron.com](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/fix-always-ask-before-opening-type-file-60489.html) and [Help Desk Geek](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/re-enable-always-ask-before-opening-this-type-of-file-check-box-in-windows/)

1. Click "Start" and type "regedit" (without quotes) in the search box. Click on "regedit.exe" from the search results.
2. Click "Yes" if a User Account Control message appears to access the registry.
3. Go to the following key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ Shell \ **AttachmentExecute**.
4. Look for a key consisting of a long string of letters and numbers.

   - These keys represent the file types you told Windows not to ask about when opening
   - The key may vary depending on the web browser you were using when you disabled the option.
   - For Internet Explorer, you will see `{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` as a key under the AttachmentExecute key.
5. Select one of the keys under the **AttachmentExecute** key.

   - The right pane contains a (Default) value plus values for each of the file types for which you turned off the Always ask before opening this type of file check box.
   - Click a key to see its associated file type in the right pane.
   - Right-click on the file type and click "Delete."
6. Click "Yes" to confirm and then exit the registry. Windows will once again prompt you with a warning message when you try to open that file type.

Comment: It doesn't help me, because as I said I have Windows 10. And this is about Windows XP and Windows 7